# ArrayFormula expansion error while reformatting phone numbers in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

[image]

I have a group of multi format phone numbers in a sheets column. I want to remove all non numeric digits and conditionally add a 1 in front (if its not there already). So far I have:

```
=ArrayFormula( (REGEXREPLACE( E4:E , "([^0-9]+)" , "" ) )
```

which I have placed in F4. An error has occurred in F4 which you can see in the sheet. When expanded it reads :

```
Error Array result not expanded because it would overwrite data in F16
```

F16 is the 803 number on the right. But I WANT it to overwrite all those numbers and reformat the number, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't re-format them on the spot by re-writing actual data by **`ARRAYFORMULA`**. your options are:

- you will need to delete the whole **F5:F** column
- you will need to put your **`ARRAYFORMULA`** into an empty column
- you will need to restrict your **`ARRAYFORMULA`** with **`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`** like:

---

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(REGEXREPLACE(E16:E, "([^0-9]+)", ""), 12)
```

Comment: OK thanks, I cleared the row. Then inserted the formula at the top, and it worked.